# Revert to original configuration in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins server hosted, which has a master node and couple of other slave configurations. Last night, the job that triggers the matrix based build configuration failed. I did a restart and performed clean up jobs via Jenkins but none of those fixed the issue. The initial error that was logged was:

`FATAL: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel`

Following which I performed a reload configuration from disk,followed by a manual restart via `<jenkins_job_url>/restart`, which even worsened the build system. The master went offline due to unavailability of space in `/tmp` folder, which I fixed by cleaning up the space. Following which I observed that the original slave server configuration is no longer seen. I had slave-0 and slave-1 still there, but slave-2 was no longer present. Instead, it got replaced with slave-3 configuration. Now the slave 0's and 1's seems to be working fine. However, slave 3's build are failing due to `Failed to mkdirs`. Is there a way I could revert back to the original configuration from where I started, since the steps I performed seems to make sense initially, but I had no idea it had so many repercussions? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE1: I guess I should have used some of the configuration backup plugins available in Jenkins, but is there some specific directory other than $JENKINS_HOME where these configurations gets stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always backup ${JENKINS_HOME} before doing major changes.

Even better is to have a job based on time trigger that will do this for you once in a while.

Other than that - only physically restoring the hard drive to a previous state will get back your old configs. Once a config is overwritten in Jenkins - it is gone. Except when you are using [Job Config History](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) plugin. Though keeping manually created backups is better in my opinion: where's the insurance that JobConfigHistory won't disappear along with the job configs? :)

Aside from that, the mentioned plugin tracks system config too.

Comment: I went to add an Artifactory server to the config via the GUI, and it ended up propegating plugin info for a ton of plugins, not just Artifactory, and that subsequently wrecked the ability to do a lot of things. I would not consider adding an Artifactory server to your Jenkins config as a major change, but apparently it _can_ due to unpropegated plugin interaction after installation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Zloj, there is no easy way to repair once the changes gets overwritten. I ended up fixing the issues by deleting the slaves that were not working, remapping the existing builds to the newer slaves that I created via Copy of the existing slaves that were working, reducing the number of builds(by removing the ones from the matrix that aren't required) and finally, taking a backup via https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup plugin and backing up the configuration at Stash :)

Answer (score 0):

for windows just delete .jenkins folder in your home directory. This will revert you to the original settings.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using SCM Sync Configuration plugin and that has saved our butt many times.  It stores all job configuration including global config in bitbucket.  But the latest plugin will say that its no longer maintained.  but I was able to pull the source code from github and rebuild it ourselves.

one word of caution...don't use global variables for storing passwords and keys...this plugin will sync them all to github. Strictly use Jenkins Credentials.